# Oauth2 code from mobile app

Tags: django, redirect, oauth-2.0

I'm writing an Android app which will authenticate itself using OAuth2 to a Web server under my control.

I'm using Apache Amber on the client side, and oauth2app with Django on the server side.

From the client, I can generate an authorization request, and start a browser Activity that goes to a page asking whether to allow the client access, and after answering in the affirmative, redirects to a page with a "code" parameter.

But how do I get the "code" back to my client, in order to make the subsequent access_token request?

Do I need to bypass the browser entirely? How would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different blog post, specific to OAuth 2:

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/08/06/oauth-2-0-flow-android/

The trick is to fire up a new Activity whose content is provided by a WebView (rather than a layout). You can attach a handler to the WebView that's called on the redirect to the page containing the "code" parameter.

Some of the specifics in the blog post concern Google APIs, but so far my experiments suggest that it will work in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a couple of choices here.

The `redirect_uri` parameter will indicate to the server where it should send the code.
From the [`ouath2app` docs](http://hiidef.github.com/oauth2app/authorize.html):

> If a request is authorized, Authorizer:grant_response() will serialize an object into a JSON response will return a redirect response to the client’s redirect_uri with information on the authorization code passed as query string parameters (response_type CODE) or access token passed as URI fragments.

So armed with that:

1. If that value is a location on your server, then your mobile browser is going to get the value as part of the redirect. Specifically, you're trying to read the URI fragments in the redirect. I believe this is the intended usage for an application like yours. [This blog post](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/10/oauth-flow-in-android-app/) seems to have code that might be relevant, under the section "Retrieving the access token".
2. Alternatively, as you pointed out, you could send the token to a different handler on your server, and then pass it back to your client. It must the callback URL defined in the service.

Comment: The blog post you cite looks like it may have what I need -- a callback that runs when the code is generated for the redirect URI. Thanks! I'd like the browser to run, in fact, because I don't want the user to enter login credentials in my app.