# Get authorization_key in Django OAuth2 API without client_secrent

Tags: android, django, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get OAuth2 working with Django to allow access to an API without having to log in with Django credentials. I'm using django-tastypie for the API and django-oauth2-provider for the OAuth2 authentication. It's all being tied together using [this](http://ianalexandr.com/blog/building-a-true-oauth-20-api-with-django-and-tasty-pie.html) post as a guideline.

I've gotten the basic OAuth workflow to work (exactly the same as in the "Testing the Provider" section of the blog post above) but obviously with my own model and username/password. I now need to get this working on Android, but I've run into a snag with the client_secret.

The recommendation seems to be to not have the client_secret stored on or transmitted to the android device since it won't always be secure. I found [this](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified) post suggesting that for mobile devices there is an OAuth flow allowing OAuth authentication without having to use the client_secret (under the section conveniently titled "Mobile Apps"). I can get the grant code using the url ending in "/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" but when I attempt to use get the authorization_token with the returned code, I still have to provide a client_id and client_secret. This seems to be because of django-oauth2-provider always requiring the client_id and client_secret.

My question, then, is how can I get the authorization_token without having to store the client_secret on the Android device or sending the client_secret as POST data? I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223829/oauth2-code-from-mobile-app) question, which seems similar and helped me figure out how to get the grant_code back, but I can't find anything about getting the authorization_token without the client_secret.

If that isn't possible, how can I automatically get the client_id/client_secret to the device and what are suggestions for securing it?

Comment: did you finally found a solution to get the token without sending the client_secret in django-oauth2-provider?

Comment: No, I didn't. I ended up using normal WebViews and HTTP authorization to get this to work.

Comment: Any news on this? I'm stuck with the same problem and I can't believe there are no clues. I've been reading two days and I can't find anything

Comment: I never got this working and instead went with a workflow like this:

Comment: @dabad I never got this working and instead went with a workflow where the user logs in to the remote API initially to get their secret and then for subsequent syncs it prompts for the user credentials and sends the client secret with the requests, but it's not optimal. The project this was for was eventually scrapped anyway. FWIW, I think a simple OAuth 1 API key would be the better option since it doesn't require client credentials more than once (when you get the key) and it allows setting permissions for that key. You could also take a look at Kerberos and SPNEGO, but that's more involved.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834462/django-oauth2-authentication-with-client-id-and-client-secret-hardcded/53847360#53847360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834462/django-oauth2-authentication-with-client-id-and-client-secret-hardcded/53847360#53847360)